# Composite Foreign Key lost in merge() operation (JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee

Imagine an `Employee` Entity that references a `Department` using a **Compound Key**:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="dept_country", referencedColumnName="country"),
      @JoinColumn(name="dept_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   })
   private Department dept;
   ...
```

In a Stateless Session Bean, I associate an Employee with a Department, by setting the appropriate attribute:

```
employee.setAbc(abc);
System.out.println(entityManager.contains(aDepartment)));  //true
employee.setDepartment(aDepartment);
employee.setXyz(xyz);
entityManager.merge(employee);
```

=> *All attributes are correctly persisted (updated) into the database, except the* **Department**.

I wonder if this is related to the compound key, because when I look at the Hibernate SQL in the background,  exactly those foreign key columns are missing.

```
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write] Hibernate:
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write]     update
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write]         employees
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write]     set
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write]         abc=?,
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write]         xyz=?,
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write]     where
14:46:18 INFO  [STDOUT#write]         id=?
```

I hope I missed something trivial...

Comment: Does `Department` have a collection of `Employee`s? Show it, please.

Comment: No, there is no reference in the other direction. (One-way navigation.)   I composed this example to present my question as simple as possible. Actually, in reality, my compound key is composed out of more columns.  But I was hoping that that is not relevant at this stage and that I made a junior's mistake...  Thx anyway!

Comment: Also remarkable: In a UnitTest it works fine. I observe the problem only in the Application Server, when part of a Stateless Session Bean (JBoss6, Hibernate 3.5.0)

Comment: @Jan If possible post your own answer when you solve your issue and let me know. Try to use property access strategy instead

Comment: SUre I will.  Unfortunately, no solution yet.  Switch to Property Access Strategy didn't help.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet of the `Department` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shoot me!

As I mentioned, I made up the `Employee`/`Department` code snippet above to clarify my case.  I shouldn't have done this!  I ommitted a key element: the `updatable` flag

Actually, my case looks as follows:

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="dept_country", referencedColumnName="country", insertable = false, updatable = false),
      @JoinColumn(name="dept_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   })
```

And the answer to the question is fairly obvious: Switch to `updatable = true`

I'm sorry!

P.S: Still, I'm puzzled why it worked in my Unit Tests and not in the App Server